# VueJS: Dynamic props based on v-select item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

I have got a chart which uses properties.

```
<template>
    <v-row>
      <v-col col="12" sm="12">
        <Chart :data="series2"></Chart> ### This chart receives the props
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-select
          item-color="red"
          item-text="muh"
          v-model="e7"
          :items="items"
          label="Select"
          single
          chips
          hint="Which series do you want?"
          persistent-hint
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

This is my script with the series.

```
<script>
import Chart from "./Chart"

    export default {

    data: function () {
      return {
        e7: [],
        series1: [1,2,3,4,5],
        series2: [5,6,5,6,5],
        series3: [5,4,3,2,1],
        items: ["series1", "series2", "series3"]
      }
    },
     components: {
        Chart
    },
  }

</script>
```

Passing the props works fine, but I want the `v-select` to change the selected series (props) based on the selected item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<Chart :data="$data[e7]"></Chart>
```

Where `e7` is the `v-model` attribute for `v-select`.

Comment: does not work unfortunately. The chart remains empty, no errors or warnings